# How do I only list specific files with 'ls' in bash?

Tags: bash

I was wondering how I can list files with `ls` in bash that will only list a specific subset of files?

For example, I have a folder with 10000 files, some of which are named:
`temp_cc1_covmat` and `temp_cc1_slurm`, but the values of 1 range from 1-1000.

So how would I list only say, `temp_cc400_slurm`-`temp_cc_499_slurm`?

I want to do this as I would like to queue files on a supercomputer that only ends with slurm. I could do `sbatch *_slurm` but there are also a lot of other files in the folder that ends with `_slurm`.

Comment: Don't use `ls` to feed another program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `Brace Expansion` in `bash`:

```
temp_cc{400..499}_slurm
```

To list these file use:

```
echo temp_cc{400..499}_slurm
```

or:

```
printf "%s\n" temp_cc{400..499}_slurm
```

or even `ls`:

```
ls temp_cc{400..499}_slurm
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Additional query: is `echo temp_cc{400..499}_slurm` internally equivalent to `for f in temp_cc{400..499}_slurm; do echo ${f}; done;`?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent and there is no need to run a for loop if range is not huge.

Comment: TIL: thanks! Is there an advantage to looping for "very big" sets? If so, what?

Comment: Not because of any advantage but if your glob pattern matches large number of files then you can get **Argument list too long** error. [See this article for more info](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/)

Comment: @msanford: Those are not equivalent, because the first will print the items separated by spaces, whereas the second will print them separated by newlines.

Comment: Thanks for the specification @ruakh. I meant with regard to the iteration mechanism, still a worthy note.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `?` wildcard:

```
$ ls temp_cc4??_slurm
```

`man 7 glob`:

```
Wildcard matching
   A  string  is  a  wildcard pattern if it contains one of the characters
   '?', '*' or '['.  Globbing is the operation  that  expands  a  wildcard
   pattern  into  the list of pathnames matching the pattern.  Matching is
   defined by:

   A '?' (not between brackets) matches any single character.
```

The **argument list too long** error applies using the `?` also. I tested with `ls test?????` and it worked but with `ls test[12]?????` I got the error. (Yes, you could `ls temp_cc4[0-9][0-9]_slurm` also.)